# Shimano Nexus 3 coaster brake screeching sound

Tags: brakes, shimano, internally-geared-hub, nexus, coaster

When I brake hard/er with my Shimano Nexus 3 coaster brake it makes a loud screeching sound. Like really loud, everybody on the street would hear it and turn around. Since I know it's all internal all I used to do was grease it up from the outside heavily with this banana organic whatever lube I had. That used to silence it a little but not entirely. It still made a very bad sound when braking very hard.

Basically - I need maintenance/lubrication instructions for a Shimano Nexus 3 Speed coaster brake. I only found a disassembly guide but no information on lubrication.

Anybody have any clue about this???

(the break is about one year old, I ride 5 miles every working day...so yeah, shouldn't be like that)

Comment: Where did you find information about 2 types of lubricants?All I could see is that Y-041 20800 Internal Hub Grease should be used for it.

Comment: You are right, what I read was not specific for this model. "An internal-gear hub with a coaster brake may need more than one type of lubricant. Follow manufacturer's recommendations."  (http://www.sheldonbrown.com/coaster-brakes.html)

Comment: That may actually be correct. I have a bicycle with the same brake and I managed to find [this](http://si.shimano.com/php/download.php?file=pdf/dm/DM-SG0005-00-ENG.pdf) document. It does have a lubrication part at the end, that uses a different type of oil for cleaning.

Comment: This just went away, I have no idea why. It just stopped at some point.

Comment: Interesting. I had similar issue and the local bike shop told me that there's a component inside that gets worn out with braking that needs replacing from time to time... I didn't take the time to actually track it down in the service manual, so I don't know what it is.