# 6'5 330 pd rider. Need Commuter bike ideas

Tags: heavy, clydesdale, tall

I am 6'5 (195cm) weight fluctuates between 300-330 lbs (136-150 kg) Looking for commuter bike for Nashville. Hilly terrain. Budget 300-900 US dollars. Any suggestions?

Comment: How tall are you?  I suspect your best starting point would be a steel fat tire bike with 26" wheels as smaller wheels will be stronger.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  I'm afraid that specific recommendation questions aren't on-topic because the answers are frequently overly specific for a generally useful question, and the answers don't age well either.

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/79203/how-to-choose-a-bike-for-a-very-tall-and-heavy-person/79204#79204

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52492/what-would-be-a-good-style-of-bike-for-big-guys

Comment: The question doesn't necessarily need to be closed. It can be changed to two questions: 1- is it possible to find a bike frame maker who mass-produces bike frames for someone heavier than 115 kg (the typical maximum weight quoted in bicycle sheets), and 2- does any wheel builder make wheels that can take 60+ kg. If you can't find a bicycle off-the-shelf, you might at least be able to assemble it, without having to go the route of building a custom frame + wheels.

Comment: Here is a different but related question: It makes sense for taller people to be heavier, at least at the same level of athleticism, and yet a bicycle sold in sizes from XS to XL is quoted as having "maximum combined weight of bicycle + rider not to exceed so-and-so kg." The fact that the XS frame is slightly lighter leaves even less room for the taller-and-heavier rider who selects the XL frame. One ought to expect that an XL frame would be _designed_ for a heavier person, and likewise an XS frame could be made more nimble. Why is an XL frame not designed for a heavier rider?

Comment: @Sam - It, or the two you suggest, are dup(s) of numerous questions we already have.  I really don't see anything in the OP's questions that a search of this site would not answer.