# Ultra durable MTB for heavyweight rider (370lbs)?

Tags: mountain-bike, heavy, clydesdale

Some might remember me from [this post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/super-heavyweight-biker-keeps-destroying-dutch-bikes). So basically after finding a fix for my dutch bike I was riding around London I now actually moved back to Germany. To the countryside to be exact and to the hilly countryside as well! With lots of forest. So now I am looking into building or buying a very rigid MTB. I will be mostly riding in the woods.

I have also considered an E-Bike for extra boost up those hills but I am not sure if that makes sense or not. The [KTM Mighty XL](https://www.ktm-bikes.at/fileadmin/user_upload/ktm_v1/pdf_bikes/798422.pdf) looks really good as far as ebikes go. It is officially rated up to 170kg (~370lbs) but that is actually for the whole bike + rider and baggage. So it's more like 150kg (~330lbs) for the rider. The price tag is probably fair but at about 4000 USD you could also buy a car for that. I am considering it anyways.

However I also want to consider regular MTBs.

**What are some features or things that I should look at that would indicate a bike that can take heavy loads — or that you would recommend or should I  have to go for a custom built?**

In the past I was given a quote for a [custom built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcURf.jpg) back in London by [SBC Cycles](http://www.sbccycles.com). Great guys but I couldn't spare the coins at that time so waited until [I found the working solution for my dutchie](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/super-heavyweight-biker-keeps-destroying-dutch-bikes). The built was based on a Surly Troll frame even though that bike was conceptualised for the city but could probably easily be altered to be an MTB aka different tyres.

In general I was wondering as well - is the MTB market completely international or would I find totally different makes in Germany than in the US?

Comment: I will mostly be cycling in the woods which can be fairly rough ground after rain

Comment: Tried to make it less a shopping question.

Comment: Well it will be hard to find anything suitable with 370lbs. I just checked the weigth limit of the Surly Troll and it is 355lbs. But in general you should check about everything. Especially if you want to go ride in the woods. But I think you will need something custom build as I don't think any manufactures consideres your weight class. Most manufactures build bikes in which can be used with a weigth of 120-130kg. In general you will get bikes from most us manufacturers and some german brands. In which part of Germany exactly do you live? Perhaps I could help you or point out a shop.

Comment: @nollak Heidelberg

Comment: @nollak also on weight limits - I used to ride a steel frame bike that was officially rated up to only 120kg (~260lbs). No problems whatsoever - my problem was always the wheels.

Comment: @Nico In that case I could perhaps help you build a bike if you are going the custom route I live nearby in Viernheim. Yeah I think the wheels are a big factor. I think I would contact a local wheelbuilder for these. I got some wheels made by Sören Speer from Frankfurt which are really excellent quality. I think some heavy duty wheels build by a good wheelbuilder would be the way to go.

Comment: Oh, awesome. You are really close. Let's get in touch, how can I reach you? Or how do you want to contact me? Cheers

Comment: @Nico yeah altough I am moving near Karlsruhe in a few month but that also gives me more workshop place for my bikes ;) just shot me a quick e-mail to me@n0ll4k.de.

Comment: @Nico easycomposites.co.uk seem to be helpful when it comes to doing calcs/recommendations on how to join carbon fiber tubes for certain specs. There are several videos online on how to make a carbon fiber frame yourself (thus saving a lot of money), and easycomposites have premade tubes. I am looking at building a carbon bike myself. It might be an idea to make test joins and then test them with machines for strength, just for peace of mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have stepped away from an ebike and am in the process of ordering a [Schauff Sumo Offroad](http://www.schauff.de/schauff/index.php?language=d&action=fahrrad&typ=&label=&gender=&id=1620&jahr=2018) which has a guaranteed max load of 200kg(440lbs!!!).

Edit 06/21/2018: I just received my Schauff custom bike. Here are some pictures: https://www.pic-upload.de/gal-1166769/gd4vz/1.html

Answer (score 5):

As you probably know specific product recommendations are off topic here. However, three recommendations:

1. Overbuilt wheels, heavy duty rim, 44 or 48 spokes.
2. The biggest tire you can run, especially on the rear.
3. Consider a full suspension bike. A 90kg rider coming off a big drop is going to generate as much force as you will going over a pothole.

Props for your efforts to keep riding.

Comment: is there a place to discuss specific equipment?

Comment: There is a chat room associated with this site:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome. Several other bike forums out there on the net that are easily findable via Google

Comment: I'm not sure a FS bike will work out.  In most cases the shock is unlikely to take enough pressure to function properly.  I quick google didn't throw up any shock that supported a rider weight over 280lb.

Comment: @Andy P - agreed with Andy P, been on a couple of rides recently with high-priced bikes rear dampers failing on fairly lightweight riders. Might be bad luck on our part, but still.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if the fat tire bike fad has also hit Europe, but if it has, then fat tire mountain bikes give you many more options.

Fat tire bikes tend to be massively overbuilt. First, they’re not trying to be lightweight in any way. Second, the thick wheels and tires mean that forks, axles, dropouts, and frames also need to be thicker. Spoke counts also tend to be very high.

[image: fat bike]

So they tend to be very sturdy and the fat, thick tires are very lush to ride on. Certainly something to consider.

Comment: The rolling resistance is enormous though and I’m not sure they are actually more sturdy than a normal mountainbike.